# Spring cloud bus/kafka : org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException on application shutdown

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka, spring-cloud-bus

We intend to use spring-cloud-bus with kafka as a binder in order to notify the services after configuration changes. All works fine but we have this following exception during service shutdown :

```
WARN 48116 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Failed to stop bean 'inputBindingLifecycle'

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name '****************.errors.bridge': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:220) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1115) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.destroyErrorInfrastructure(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:789) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.access$300(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:90) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder$2.afterUnbind(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:443) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinding.unbind(DefaultBinding.java:168) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.unbindConsumers(BindingService.java:351) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindableProxyFactory.unbindInputs(AbstractBindableProxyFactory.java:156) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.InputBindingLifecycle.doStopWithBindable(InputBindingLifecycle.java:66) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:608) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindingLifecycle.stop(AbstractBindingLifecycle.java:68) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.InputBindingLifecycle.stop(InputBindingLifecycle.java:34) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindingLifecycle.stop(AbstractBindingLifecycle.java:85) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.InputBindingLifecycle.stop(InputBindingLifecycle.java:34) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStop(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:238) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$300(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.stop(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:377) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.stopBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:210) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.stop(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:116) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.stop(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1370) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStop(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:251) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$300(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.stop(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:377) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.stopBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:210) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onClose(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:128) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1022) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$1.run(AbstractApplicationContext.java:949) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
```

The shutdown ends up happening after 30 seconds (default value of spring.lifecycle.timeoutPerShutdownPhase)

```
INFO 48116 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Failed to shut down 1 bean with phase value 2147482647 within timeout of 30000ms: [inputBindingLifecycle]
```

I can decrease the timeout value but I don't think that is the right thing to do.

I founded a similar issue https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1064 raised on spring-cloud-netflix project and still open.

Is there any way to escape this exception?

We use spring boot 2.3.4 and spring cloud Hoxton.SR8.

Thanks in advance for your help and feedback.